# How to refresh mysql posts every 1 second

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use ajax to save user posts/comments into a mysql table without page refresh.

First: I have this `<div id="posts-container"></div>`

Second: I've tried using Jquery load() to loop in table and echo the posts, with the following code:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
                           $('.posts-container').load("refresh_p.php").fadeIn();
                       }, 0 );
```

But it doesn't work, page refreshes but content doesn't load, anybody knows why?

Third: If i copy the code that contains `refresh_p.php` and paste into the  data gets loaded successfully. A little weird? Yes. Hope get any help :)

**EDIT:**
I fixed it, the problem was in refresh_p.php it was expecting the parameter 'profile_id'
i modified the function to this:

1: profile.php

```
search_user = document.getElementById('user_from').value; 
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
                           $('.posts-container').load("refresh_p.php?search_user="+search_user).fadeIn();
                       }, 5000 );
```

2: refresh_p.php

```
$profile_id = $_GET['search_user'];
```

All good, but now the whole page refreshes every 5 seconds. I just want the div 'post-container' to refresh.

I've used this function before to refresh a chat box and it worked, only refreshes the div i wanted to. but here it refreshes the entire page.

Comment: If you're going to refresh every 1 second, you're better off learning web sockets - that's quite intensive.

Comment: does the refresh_p.php contains php codes ?

Comment: Every *one second*? You'll be creating quite a load there.. it's possible the data is cached and when you load it again, it's seeing the cached version.

Comment: Don't use `setInterval`. Do recursive calls on jQuery load complete, this way you make sure that calls are sent one AFTER another, not at the same time.

Comment: @MackieeE Hard to say how intensive it is without knowing a) the query and table structure, b) how many simultaneous users will have this polling going. It's certainly not optimized though.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah Yup it contains 3 tables with relationships. These tables work with logged_user: ID based on $_SESSION and profile_id based on a parameter send in profile.php?search_user='profile_id'

Comment: The author is setting the autorefresh to ever 0 seconds here...basically equivalent to every 3ms.

Comment: Yep, set your refresh to 1000(ms).

Comment: Also, why not use json data ($.get) in combination with some templating, while you're at it.

Comment: @crush It doesn't matter, it would be making an HTTP request every second, nevermind the Database here.

Comment: @jgroenen I will try this way.

Comment: @MackieeE My point is that it is hard to label it intensive without knowing more about the author's setup. If it's a 1 user based system with a localhost HTTP server, then making calls every 1 second is nothing. As I stated above though, it's certainly not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `setInterval`. Do recursive calls on jQuery load complete, this way you make sure that calls are sent one AFTER another, not at the same time.

Try this:

```
var auto_refresh =  function () {
    $('.posts-container').load("refresh_p.php", function(){
            setTimeout(auto_refresh, 800);
        }).fadeIn();
}
auto_refresh();
```

Also, `.fadeIn()` only works the first time, after that you have to hide the div before showing it again.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P4P9a/1/ (might be slow because it is loading an entire page).

**LE**: As I think you are not returning an `HTML` page you should use `$.get` instead of `$.load` .

```
 $('.posts-container').get("refresh_p.php", function(data){
          $(this).html(data);
          setTimeout(auto_refresh, 800);
 }).fadeIn();
```

Comment: This code works successfully, the problem here is when the div refreshes the data that contains refresh_p.php doesn't load.

Comment: The old data? You can remove it by doing first `$('.posts-container').html('');` (before `.load()`)

Comment: No. 'posts-container' appears without posts (empty).

Comment: @Cristy Apologies, I double checked it, must be something wrong with the `refresh_p.php` =)

Comment: @MackieeE :) No problem, but I still think he wants to use `$.get()` instead (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: @Cristy This worked, but after data loads the pages scrolls down, how to prevent that?

Comment: Why does the page scroll down? Is it because the `div` with the data is getting bigger?

Comment: @Cristy Yea. 'posts-container' has height:auto;

Answer (score 0):

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $('.posts-container').load("refresh_p.php").fadeIn(50);
},1000);
```

Changed the interval from 0 (which would just create a crazy load...) to 1000ms (1 second). Should work if your path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your interval is long enough for your requests to finish. Also think about less real-time options, such as sending an array of messages every 15 seconds, showing them one after another on the client side. Optimize your server side for quick response using caching and also think about using json data and client side templating instead of html responses.

Comment: The calls are asynchronous, so they will finish. The order in which they display the results might be out of order though.

Comment: I'm not saying they won't finish, but you don't want them to run in parallel.

Comment: How do you know the author doesn't want them to run in parallel?

Comment: For all we know, the data is changing every 1000ms. If request A takes 2350ms to complete before request B is sent, we've missed 2 changes. Perhaps, the author is deleting records before inserting, thus making it impossible to send all changes between the last request and the latest request. Now you're losing data. However, just like polling every 1s is sub-optimal, so would this type of db setup. I'm just saying that the author hasn't given us enough information to determine how to optimize his/her system.

Comment: All I'm saying is that he can use an interval, as long as he makes sure the interval is large enough. But of course this problem is very general.